# Async Command in fable Elmish

Tags: f#, fable-f#, elmish

I have this code I'm running using Fable Elmish and Fable remoting to connect to a Suave server. I know that the server works because of postman and there are variations of this code that does call the server

```
 let AuthUser model : Cmd<LogInMsg> =
        let callServer = async {
                let! result = server.RequestLogIn model.Credentials
                return result
            }
        let result = callServer |> Async.RunSynchronously
        match result with
        | LogInFailed x -> Cmd.ofMsg (LogInMsg.LogInRejected x) 
        | UserLoggedIn x -> Cmd.ofMsg (LogInMsg.LogInSuccess x)
```

The `callServer` line in the let result fails with `Object(...) is not a function`, but I don't understand why. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to Fable docs `Async.RunSynchronously` is not supported, though I'm not sure if that is causing your problem. Anyway you should structure your code so that you don't need to block asynchronous computations. In case of Elmish you can use `Cmd.ofAsync` to create a command out of an async that dispatches messages returned by the async when it completes.

```
let AuthUser model : Cmd<LogInMsg> =
    let ofSuccess result =
        match result with
        | LogInFailed x -> LogInMsg.LogInRejected x
        | UserLoggedIn x -> LogInMsg.LogInSuccess x
    let ofError exn = (* Message representing failed HTTP request *) 
    Cmd.ofAsync server.RequestLogIn model.Credentials ofSuccess ofError
```

Hopefully this helps.